# DOM chaining methods which returns dom elements in JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, chaining

I am reading a book about  JavaScript specifically the chapter that talks about chaining methods. I know how chaining works. This is what i've done so far(An example of DOM chaining).

```js
var app  = {};
app.dom =
{
      
        createElement : function(type)
        {
            this.element = document.createElement(type);
           
            this.html = function(html)
            {
                this.element.innerHTML = html;
                return this;
            };
            this.css = function(prop,value)
            {
          
                this.element.style[prop] = value;
                return this;
            }
            this.getElement = function()
            {
                return this.element;
            }
        }
}
new app.dom.createElement('p').html('hello word').css('border','1px solid');
```

This code works fine. it creates a p element , adds html code inside and adds css properties. But my question is how can i append this created node to body without doing this (calling the getElement which returns the node element)

```
document.body.appendChild(new app.dom.element('p').html('hello world').css('border','1px solid').getELement());
```

Instead, i dont want to use the getElement method of the constructor function, just every time i invoke the html method or css method, the node element(this.element) can be appended to body directly, like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(new app.dom.element('p').html('hello world').css('border','1px solid'));
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not create another function called `appendTo` so that you are able to do the following: `yourElement.appendTo(document.body)`

Comment: No, there isn't. If you want to keep on chaining, there's no way to know if the chain stops or if it keeps on going so you'll need a 'terminating call' to get the underlying element.

Comment: so there is no way i can do this without using methods like 'appendtTo'. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As your code is bad already, You can write something similar to this (It's very bad idea, So please DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION):

```js
var app = {};
app.dom = {
    createElement: function createElement(type) {
        element = document.createElement(type);

        element.html = function(html) {
            this.innerHTML = html;
            return this;
        }.bind(element);

        element.css = function(prop, value) {

            this.style[prop] = value;
            return this;
        }.bind(element);

        return element;
    }
};


document.body.appendChild(app.dom.createElement('p').html('hello world').css('border','1px solid'));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!!! . but why this code is bad?. I dont have  much knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: It's bad because changing the behavior of a native objects (or so called host objects) Is very very bad practice it may break something or may not work sometimes. The best way to do it is by writing a method like getElement(), But never pass to the element object!